# mvnw not generating test directory for jhipster 4.10.0

Tags: jhipster

I have deleted the default test directory generated by ./mvnw. Now running maven doesn't generate test repository no more. I need some help please

Comment: maven does not generate the test directory, it only uses it. This directory is generated by jhipster command, restore it from git commit.

Comment: I have modified the domain classes, I need it to be generated, how can I do?

Comment: Is it another question?

Comment: As @GaëlMarziou points, the test directory is generated by jhipster. If you have a .jdl, running the command `jhipster import-jdl yourFile.jdl` will generate it again . `jhipster entity YourEntity` will generate that code again too, (option `Yes, re generate the entity`) but only for that entity.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, will try it out